# Ajax requests out of memory

Tags: php, ajax, html

So I am working on this project where I have to make a photo sharing site, I select the photos and then upload them, send the link via email, and then the person goes on the link and downloads the photos. Everything works great when I have few photos and when not exceeding 100MB of data, when I go beyond that everything becomes unstable.

First of I am using HTML5's `FileReader()`.The logic is the following:
I use `FileReader()` to transform each photo into a base64 code and every 3 photos transformed I send a 3 photos long base64 string via `Ajax` to a `php` file which then transforms the code into photos and uploads them into a folder on the server.

If I have 300 photos selected I do 100 `ajax` requests.
The first problem if if I exceed ~150MB of data `ajax` will give me an `uncaught exception out of memory` error.
The second problem is if I chose over 20-30 files the brower some times gets unresponsive even crashes..

Any suggestions what can I do ? Maybe the whole idea is wrong and I should start somewhere else, please help.

This is the code:

```
//Forming the inputs
$(document).on("change","#fileUp",function(e){
            var file = null;
            var files = e.target.files; //FileList object
            var picReader = new FileReader();

            $(".eventPop").html("");
            $(".howMany").html("");

            $(".eventPop").show();
            $(".eventPop").append('<div class="adding"><img src="../public/cuts/uploading.gif" width="60px"></div>');

            countUp = parseInt(countUp) + parseInt(files.length);

            for(var i=0; i<=files.length-1; i++){

                file = files[i];

                var str = file.name.split(".")[0];

//
                //var picReader = new FileReader();

                if (file.type == "image/jpeg" || file.type == "image/png")
                {
                    picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                            count++;

                            var picFile = event.target;

                            $(".photos").append("<input type='hidden' id='ph"+count+"' get='"+picFile.result+"' /> ");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    countUp--;
                }


                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

});


//actual ajax requests
$(document).on('click','.uploadImages',function(){

        info[1] = "4hold"+1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)+"_"+(new Date).getTime();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index/loadIntoDB",
            dataType:"text",
            data: {info: info},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(result){
            }
        });

        if (nrConfig > count)
        {
            nrConfig = count;
        }
        $(".eventPop").show();
        $(".eventPop").html("");
        $(".eventPop").append('<div class="adding"><p>Uploading files...'+( (nrConfig/count) * 100).toFixed(0)+'%</p></div>');
        for(var i=1; i<=parseInt(nrConfig)+1; i++)
        {
            if (i == parseInt(nrConfig)+1)
            {
                info[2] = info[2].substring(2, info[2].length);
                uploadImages(nrConfig,1);               
            }
            else
            {
                //info[0] = i+"-"+info[0];
                info[2] = info[2]+"--"+$("#ph"+i+"").attr("get");
            }
        }
    });


function uploadImages(i,d){
         info['3'] = i;
         info['4'] = d;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index/receiveImages",
            dataType:"json",
            data: {info : info },
            beforeSend : function (){
                //
            },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(result){
                for(index=result['leftOff']['1']; index <= result['info']['4']-1; index++)
                {
                    if (result[index]['filesize'] < 1000000)
                    {
                        result[index]['filesize'] = Math.floor(result[index]['filesize']/1000)+"kb";
                        $("#ph"+result[index]['id']).append("<div class='filesize'>"+result[index]['filesize']+"</div>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[index]['filesize'] = (result[index]['filesize']/1000000).toFixed(2)+"MB";
                        $("#ph"+result[index]['id']).append("<div class='filesize'>"+result[index]['filesize']+"</div>");
                    }
                    if (result[index]['filesize'].length > 0)
                    {
                        $("#ph"+result[index]['id']+" .uploading").remove();
                        $("#ph"+result[index]['id']).append("<img src='layout/cuts/check.png' title='Uploaded' class='done'>");
                        $("#ph"+result[index]['id']+" .upd").remove();
                    }
                }
                $(".eventPop").html("");
                $(".eventPop").append('<div class="adding"><p>Uploading files...'+( (result['info'][4]-1)/count * 100).toFixed(0)+'%</p></div>');

                if (((result['info'][4]-1)/count * 100).toFixed(0) == 100)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("progress").remove();
                        $(".eventPop").html("");
                        $(".eventPop").append("<div class='adding'>Upload complete!</div>");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".eventPop").html("");
                            $(".eventPop").append("<div class='adding'><div class='sendPhotos'><form action='#' onsubmit='return false;' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><label>Your email</label><input type='text' class='yemail'/><br/><label>Friend's email</label><input type='text' class='fremail'/><br/><span class='tip'><div class='triangle'></div>You can send photos to multiple friends by typing their e-mail separated by ';'.<br/>Eg. 'thomas@gmail.com ; peter@gmail.com'</span><input type='submit' name='send' class='send' value='Send'></form></div></div>");
                        },1000);
                    },1000);
                }

                if (info[2].length)
                {
                    info[2] = "";
                }
                if ( (parseInt(result['info']['4'])+parseInt(nrConfig)) >= count )
                {
                    nrConfig = count-result['info']['4']+1;
                }

                if(result['info']['4'] <= count)
                {                   
                    for(i=result['info']['4']; i <= parseInt(result['info']['4'])+parseInt(nrConfig); i++)
                    {
                        if (i == parseInt(result['info']['4'])+parseInt(nrConfig))
                        {
                            info[2] = info[2].substring(2, info[2].length);
                            uploadImages(nrConfig,result['info']['4']);         
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            info[2] = info[2]+"--"+$("#ph"+i+"").attr("get");
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP code:

```
public function receiveImages()
    {
        $string = strtok($_POST['info'][2],"--");
        $currentID = $_POST['info']['4'];
        $newArray['info']['3'] = $_POST['info']['3'];

        $newArray['leftOff']['1'] = $currentID;

        $phAdded = 0;

        while($string != false && $phAdded < $_POST['info']['3'])
        {
            $newArray[$currentID]['id'] = $currentID;
            $newArray[$currentID]['filesize'] = $this->saveImages($string,$_POST['info']['1'],$currentID);
            $currentID++;
            $phAdded++;
            $string = strtok("--");
        }

        $newArray['info']['4'] = $currentID;


        echo json_encode($newArray);
    }

public function saveImages($base64img = "",$folder = "",$currentID = "")
    {
        $newArray = array();

        if (!is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR.$folder))
        {
            mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR.$folder,0777);
        }
        $dir = UPLOAD_DIR.$folder."/";


        if (strstr($base64img,'data:image/jpeg;base64,'))
        {
            $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64img);
            $uniqid = uniqid();
            $file = $dir . $uniqid . '.jpg';

            $file_name = $uniqid.".jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            $base64img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64img);
            $uniqid = uniqid();
            $file = $dir . $uniqid . '.png';

            $file_name = $uniqid.".png";
        }

        $data = base64_decode($base64img);


        file_put_contents($file, $data);

        $size = filesize($file);
        if ($size > 1000000)
        {
            $size = number_format(($size/1000000),2)."MB";
        }
        else
        {
            $size = number_format(($size/1000),0)."kb";
        }

        return filesize($file);


    }
```

Comment: I do not see something in your code, but you have to ask yourself: Why does 3 images give more than 150MB? Some logic is wrong.

Comment: No I didn't mean that 3 images were over 150MB, after I upload 100 images that total up to 150 MB then I get the `out of memory` error. It's like the php or ajax hogs up memory or something, I don't know.

Comment: Hmm, you first should get the definitive side of the error, sounds like the client side here. Hope that's not a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909846. You should restrict your problem then to: 1. Is it a file choose dialogue problem. 2. Is it an AJAX problem. :)

Comment: Can you make an image which is above 150MB and see if a single image with that size gets over it?

Comment: I could give it a try but how will I make an image with more than 150MB ?

Comment: Hmm you are the base64 profi. ;) Iii guess, well, open photoshop and make a huuuge canvas, save it as jpeg and take this. I wonder though if the base64 conversion does something to the dpi?

Comment: BTW: Have you seen the new PHP logo? http://www.php.net/ Hahaha

Comment: lol :))) funny logo... ok I did the test with a picture that has more the 150MB and guess what, I get the `uncaught exception out of memory` error on the ajax part.

Comment: Ok, so 1) it is not the file choose dialogue!

Comment: Which is somehow acceptable, that you cannot transfer more than 150MB in one AJAX call. But how to make the calls sequentially, means AJAX sends 3 after 3? Sounds like it does one call for all. I never uploaded actually with AJAX, but do you get a response, when the upload is done?

Comment: yes I am uploading 3 by 3, which shouldn't be as much, I mean 3 photos can total up to what? max 30 MB ? But usually 10-15 MB each 3 photos, the thing is when I upload photos that don't total up to ~150MB and they total up less, everything works as intended... don't know why the problem comes above 150MB. For example I selected 175 photos and hit the upload button, it uploaded 196.88 MB of data and after that I got hit by `out of memory`, and it still had left some photos to upload from those 175 total.

Comment: Ok, so for an actual answer: The calls of `uploadImages()` are all at the same time or not one after the other. You have to check for "3 images are uploaded" -> now I can upload the next. Either you implement that before the `uploadImages()` calls, or store them in an object and loop over it -> triggering the AJAX calls sequentially.

Comment: This would have to be implemented. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress. The `oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);`. You could also do an upload progress, but only per 3 files, and only if file size is known: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/.

Comment: I see, I think I will have to rethink my whole approach on this problem, and actually use `XMLHTTPRequest` instead of `FileReader()`.

Comment: Nonono, you ARE using `XMLHTTPRequest`. ;) Just get somebody to tell the Request, that it should not send anything exceeding the limits out of the box. You will have to implement that now. ;)